# show element when checkbox is :checked in jquery

Tags: jquery

So when i tick a checkbox i want an element to show and then hide when unchecked.

```
                <div class="hndle">
                    <table class="form-table">
                        <td class="left">
                            Environmental Findings
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
                        </td>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="hndle">
                    <textarea></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="hndle">
                    <table class="form-table">
                        <td class="left">
                            Recommendations
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
                        </td>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="hndle">
                    <textarea></textarea>
                </div>
```

Okay so when the checkbox is clicked i want it to show the next div with the class hndle.(the one which has a textarea inside).

This is the jQuery code i have attempted with but no luck getting it working.

```
        $('.check').change(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(this).parents('hndle').next().show();
            }else{
                $(this).parents('hndle').next().hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry i have actually got the . in my code i must have written it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hndle` is a class of the target ancestor element, so use class selector

```js
$('.check').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.hndle').next().toggle(this.checked);
});

$('.check').closest('.hndle').next().hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hndle">
  <table class="form-table">
    <td class="left">
      Environmental Findings
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="hndle">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="hndle">
  <table class="form-table">
    <td class="left">
      Recommendations
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="hndle">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually this worked for me after changing all the $ to jQuery

Comment: @MatthewSmart you can use the dom ready handler like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LqrwkceL/2/ to use `$`

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect selector to target next handle div element. `hndle` is classname of div.Thus you need to use class selector `.` with it:

```
$('.check').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('.hndle').next().toggle(this.checked);
}).change(); // trigger event to hide on load
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jb11w59/)**

Comment: @MatthewSmart: check the fiddle